# Not able to display more than 2 recycler grid views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

I am making an app on android studio. I want to display items in a recycler view using grid layout manager. I am adding three element into the array through which I want to display the recycler view. But when I am running the app, the app is displaying only two items. I don't know what's happening. I have set the height of the recycler view as wrap content still getting this problem.

Here's my code:-

ModelClass.java:-

```
public class ModelClass {
private String recyc_show_note;


ModelClass(String recyc_show_note){
    this.recyc_show_note = recyc_show_note;
}

public String getRecyc_show_note() {
    return recyc_show_note;
}}
```

Adapter.java:-

```
 public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<ModelClass> recyc_cust_notes;

public Adapter (List<ModelClass>recyc_cust_notes){
    this.recyc_cust_notes = recyc_cust_notes;
}

@NonNull
@Override

public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String recyc_show_note = recyc_cust_notes.get(position).getRecyc_show_note();


    holder.setData(recyc_show_note);
}

@Override
//returns list size
public int getItemCount() {
    return recyc_cust_notes.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
      private TextView recycler_view_note;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
          recycler_view_note = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyc_show_note);
    }

    public void setData(String recyc_show_note) {
          recycler_view_note.setText(recyc_show_note);
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.java:-

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<ModelClass>recyc_cust_notes;
Adapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    SharedPreferences getSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("My Notes", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String note = getSharedPreference.getString("Note", null);
    initData();
    initRecyclerView();
}

private void initRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
    gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    adapter = new Adapter(recyc_cust_notes);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void initData() {
    recyc_cust_notes = new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences getSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("My Notes", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String note = getSharedPreference.getString("Note", null);
    recyc_cust_notes.add(new ModelClass(note));
    recyc_cust_notes.add(new ModelClass("note"));
    recyc_cust_notes.add(new ModelClass("sai"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your `gridLayoutManager` Orientation.
You have 2 choices to show all items:

1. Change orientation to VERTICAL
2. Change your `recyclerView` width to match-parent

Answer (score 0):

Just do it on this way

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, number_of_cols));

In XML

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_Grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Java Code

```
int cols = 3; // length of cols

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_Grid);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, cols));
adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And Remove setOrientation.